Getting numbers of figures right in a tcolorbox poster layout OR adjust natural height of sequenced posterbox
Aim
I am working on a poster which consists of one posterbox I am breaking into two columns (D1 and D2). After the posterbox ends I continue with the next posterbox (E).
First approach
The current problem of the first approach is that I have to define the end in the sequence:
    sequence=2 between C and bottom then
    3 between top and row3,

But row3 is too short because text or images are skipped/croped. row4 however is too long and the space until E is too much.
I don’t know how to adjust the last bit of  ... and row3 in a manual way with something in between of row3 and row4.
Here is the MWE:
\documentclass[
ngerman,
a4paper,
parskip=full,
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel,graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[poster,many,skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  coverage = {spread},
  poster   = {
    spacing=7mm,
    showframe,
    columns=3,
    rows=6},
  boxes={
    natural height,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    colback=white,
    boxrule=5pt,
    boxsep=14pt,
    fonttitle=\large\centering\bfseries\scshape,
    arc=10mm,
    equal height group=parbox,
  },
  fontsize = 12pt,
]

\posterbox{name=A,column=1,below=top}{First Box}
\posterbox{name=B,column=1,between=A and bottom}{Second box
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{1}
    \label{1}
  \end{minipage}
}
\posterbox{name=C,
  column=2,
  below=top,
  rowspan=2,
}{Third box

  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{2}
    \label{2}
  \end{minipage}
}
\posterbox[natural height % <--- not working
]{
  name=D,column=2,
    sequence=2 between C and bottom then
    3 between top and
    row3, % <--- row3 is too short
    % row4, % <--- row4 is too long
    }{
  Fourth box

  \lipsum[1]

  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{3}
    \label{3}
  \end{minipage}
  }
  \posterbox[natural height]{name=E,
      column=3,
      below=D2,
  }{Fifth box
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{4}
    \label{4}
  \end{minipage}
}

\posterbox{
  name=F,column=3,
  above=bottom,
  }{Sixth box}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}


Second approach
I found out that I can call the posterbox of E earlier, then E is already known and I can use it as the limit of the box of D2. With some manual adjustment of the starting point of E I can get the desired position of E and it ends D2 nicely.
BUT the numbers of the images are now not in the desired order. Since I call E before D2 the images in E have a lower number then those of D which is confusing reading columns in the order A->F.
Here is the MWE for that:
\documentclass[
ngerman,
a4paper,
parskip=full,
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel,graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[poster,many,skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  coverage = {spread},
  poster   = {
    spacing=7mm,
    showframe,
    columns=3,
    rows=6},
  boxes={
    natural height,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    colback=white,
    boxrule=5pt,
    boxsep=14pt,
    fonttitle=\large\centering\bfseries\scshape,
    arc=10mm,
    equal height group=parbox,
  },
  fontsize = 12pt,
]

\posterbox{name=A,column=1,below=top}{First Box}
\posterbox{name=B,column=1,between=A and bottom}{Second box
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{1}
    \label{1}
  \end{minipage}
}
\posterbox{name=C,
  column=2,
  below=top,
  rowspan=2,
}{Third box

  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{2}
    \label{2}
  \end{minipage}
}

  \posterbox[natural height]{name=E,
    column=3,
    at=row4,
    yshift=3.4cm % <--- manual adjustment
  }{Fifth box
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{4}
    \label{4}
  \end{minipage}
}


\posterbox[natural height % <--- not working
]{
  name=D,column=2,
    sequence=2 between C and bottom then
    3 between top and E,
    }{
  Fourth box

  \lipsum[1]

  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{3}
    \label{3}
  \end{minipage}
  }

\posterbox{
  name=F,column=3,
  above=bottom,
  }{Sixth box}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}


Summary
How can I manually adjust the end of D2 then I have the numbers of the images right or how can I fix the numbers of the images (my real document has lots of images so a manual adjustment of the counter is too tidious.)

I think it is easier to adjust the box height than fiddle with the counters. You can define a coordinate using regular pgf/tikz methods. The only trick is that you need to use the TCBPOSTER@ prefix in order to be able to use the name 'normally' inside the \posterbox.
For example,
  \coordinate (TCBPOSTER@inbetween) at ([yshift=-5pt]TCBPOSTER@row3.north);

defines a point 5pt below the top of row3 which can be used in sequence as inbetween.
    sequence=2 between C and bottom then
    3 between top and
    inbetween, % <--- is just right?

and 5pt is sufficient to accommodate the remaining part of the \posterbox.
Complete code:
\documentclass[
  ngerman,
  a4paper,
  parskip=full,
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel,graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[poster,many,skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
    coverage = {spread},
    poster   = {
      spacing=7mm,
      showframe,
      columns=3,
    rows=6},
    boxes={
      natural height,
      enhanced jigsaw,
      colback=white,
      boxrule=5pt,
      boxsep=14pt,
      fonttitle=\large\centering\bfseries\scshape,
      arc=10mm,
      equal height group=parbox,
    },
    fontsize = 12pt,
  ]
  \coordinate (TCBPOSTER@inbetween) at ([yshift=-5pt]TCBPOSTER@row3.north);

  \posterbox{name=A,column=1,below=top}{First Box}
  \posterbox{name=B,column=1,between=A and bottom}{Second box
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \captionof{figure}{1}
      \label{1}
    \end{minipage}
  }
  \posterbox{name=C,
    column=2,
    below=top,
    rowspan=2,
  }{Third box

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \captionof{figure}{2}
      \label{2}
    \end{minipage}
  }
  \posterbox[natural height % <--- not working
  ]{
    name=D,column=2,
    sequence=2 between C and bottom then
    3 between top and
    inbetween, % <--- is just right?
  }{
    Fourth box

    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \captionof{figure}{3}
      \label{3}
    \end{minipage}
  }
  \posterbox[natural height]{name=E,
    column=3,
    below=D2,
  }{Fifth box
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \captionof{figure}{4}
      \label{4}
    \end{minipage}
  }

  \posterbox{
    name=F,column=3,
    above=bottom,
  }{Sixth box}

\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}


If this reflects your real layout, you probably want to yshift=5pt the fifth box to get the top aligned with the top of the fourth box, but you probably don't want this if your layout differs significantly.

I could easily adjust the yshift= to my actual layout. it works beautifully.
